# Amazon Redshift error in Tableau

Tags: amazon-redshift, tableau-api

It is very frustrated that I have created multiple data visualization on Tableau 10 by connecting to Amazon Redshift. Everything was very well, I didn't change my custom sql query at all. However, all of a sudden, it kept showing me this error, and prevent me from creating new visualization. and now I have to open a new Tableau workbook and redo everything.:

[image]

My custom sql query in Tableau is very simply:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7
from my_table
where col1 is not null and col2 is not null
```

Do you know **is there any solution to resolve this problem?**

Comment: Why use custom sql for this? Try just connecting to the table, and add your filter conditions as data source filters. Custom sql inhibits query optimization.

Comment: I really don't like tableau filter, if I can remove those unnecessary data from query, at the very beginning, it's better. Meanwhile, when I am using the same query, but created a new Tableau workbook, everything is working fine. So, it should not be the custom query problem

Comment: If you make the filter a data source filter, it is applied to every query and is part of the data source definition, so can't be accidentally changed on a view. That has exactly the same effect as your custom query, but allows Tableau to do a better job of controlling the SQL it generates.  Might avoid the problem you are seeing.

Comment: Oh thank you! This works even better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error when I had a text sql output for a column that was modeled as number in Tableau. The error was caused by empty string sitting in that column. Try to wrap your columns with `nullif(column_name,'')`